# Sum in a discrete moment generating function

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

I am reviewing my class tutorials and we were working in a MGF in the case of a discrete random variable.
We arrive at this stage :
$$M_{X}(t)=E(e^{tx})=\sum_{x=0}^{n}{e^{tx}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x+1}}=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}(2^{n-1}e^t+2^{n-2}e^{2t}+...+2e^{(n-1)t}+e^{nt}+2^n)$$
**Could you explain to me why the sum does that ?** I think I am missing this concept that is very usefull.
(Would you mind doing the same for the product from i=0 to n)

**Edit** - How did we get the expansion from the sum?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: I removed the probability theory tag since it's about the measure-theoretic study of probability.  Plz type out your question in LaTeX and show us your attempts.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會, I made the latex edit

Comment: @MachineLearner75 I made some formatting change to your latex please check

Comment: @at-in thx for edit, I approved.  my downvote removed since a score of negative one would suffice for this question.

Comment: @MachineLearner75 can you explain what do you mean by "why the sum does that"? Are you confused by the expansion of the sum?

Comment: Yes exactly, I don't understand how we proceed from the sum to its expansion

Comment: @MachineLearner75 try putting values of x, at x = 0 you get the last term of the expansion $\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}$, similarly try other values then you can see how did we got the expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove:

> $$\sum_{x=0}^{n}{e^{tx}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x+1}}=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}(2^{n-1}e^t+2^{n-2}e^{2t}+...+2e^{(n-1)t}+e^{nt}+2^n)$$

Let's see how $\sum_{x=0}^{n}{e^{tx}2^{n-x}}$ expandes
At $x=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $2^n$
At $x=1$ $\Rightarrow$ $e^t2^{n-1}$
At $x=2$ $\Rightarrow$ $e^{2t}2^{n-2}$
I think you can see the pattern so the expansion will be
$$\sum_{x=0}^{n}{e^{tx}2^{n-x}}=(2^{n-1}e^t+2^{n-2}e^{2t}+...+2e^{(n-1)t}+e^{nt}+2^n)$$
Now divide both sides by $2^{n+1}$ and you'll get the original expansion.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{x=0}^{n}{e^{tx}2^{n-x-n-1}} & = \sum_{x=0}^{n}{e^{tx}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x+1}} \\
& = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}(2^{n-1}e^t+2^{n-2}e^{2t}+...+2e^{(n-1)t}+e^{nt}+2^n)
\end{align}
$$